# How to give folder level access only in Box through an API

Tags: api, security, box

As per the question, How do you set folder level (instead of account level) access in Box through its API. Dropbox does this very easily by giving apps folder level access only. How does this work in the Box API, to ensure user privacy?

Comment: Are you worried about legal issues?

Comment: Yes. Mainly user privacy. Don't want to have access to the user's entire account.